# Rails4 where with conditions syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to switch my app from rails 3.2 to 4.2.

```
q = User.find_all_by_attr(attr_value, :order => "name DESC", limit => 8).map { ... }
```

Since find_all_by_ is deprecated I've changed it to

```
q = User.where(:attr => attr_value, :order => "name desc", limit => 8).map { ... }
```

but now I am getting error that column name order doesn't exist.

What is a proper way to write this query in rails 4.2?

Same goes for User.find(:all). I've seen that using all is deprecated and am unable to find proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
q = User.where(:attr => attr_value).order('name DESC').limit(8).map { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. I also have :conditions in there. How should that be added?

Comment: @J.Doe .where() is for conditions only. what conditions you are talking about?

Comment: More precisely :conditions => "n >= getN()"

Comment: @J.Doe You can always chain your conditions like #=> User.where(:attr => attr_value).where("n >= getN()").order(..)